# Rstudio Removewords duda

Tags: r, inteligencia-artificial, data, rstudio

Sólo tengo una duda, si ¿Existe alguna manera de ver cuántas palabras se removieron utilizando removewords?

Gracias!

Comment: En particular no lo se, pero intentaste ver la cantidad de palabras previos al uso de la función para luego calcular la diferencia?

Comment: De echo eso estaba pensando pero si remuevo 5 palabras quisiera saber cuantas había de cada palabra

Comment: Seria bueno que aclares que `removeWorks()` es una función del paquete `tm`. Por ejemplo dando un minimo de codigo ejemplo que empieze con `library(tm)`.

Answer (score 3):

Esta es una forma:

```
z = "R es un lenguaje de programación interpretado y un ambiente de desarrollo
especializado en estadística. Es utilizado por especialistas en estadística y
en minería de datos para el diseño de herramientas de software para el análisis
estadístico de datos. Es una implementación del lenguaje S, desarrollado por
Bell Labs en 1976. Aunque R funciona principalmente a través de una herramienta
de línea de comandos, existen varias interfaces gráficas disponibles (como
RCMDR y RStudio)."
```

lista de palabras a remover

```
quitar = c("es","de","el")

zSin = removeWords(z,quitar)
```

`zSin` ya no contiene las palabras dadas en `quitar`

Para calcular cuantas se han removido de cada una de estas hay que primero separar el texto en palabras individuales, haciendo los cortes en los espacios o cortes de linea (`\n`)

```
zSeparado = strsplit(z,split = "( |\n)")[[1]]

L = sapply(X = quitar,FUN = function(x){sum(zSeparado %in% x)})
```

Resultado:

```
> L
es de el 
 1  9  2
```

Se han removido 9 "de", 2 "el" y un "es" del texto. Notar que tanto `removeWords` como el `%in%` hacen distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas